# How to create line like this

Tags: java, swt

I would like to create horizontal line like this, using SWT:
[alt text http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/2810/swthorizontalline.png](http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/2810/swthorizontalline.png)

Of course, without red frame

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I remember well create a simple Label and as a second initialization argument pass this: `SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL`.